# Does Instagram have share button or not?

Tags: instagram-api

I have googled for several hours but I didn't find any article and documentation related to instagram shared button on the web. Does it have or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: the question & answer is from 2015, is this still relevant on 2019?

Comment: @topher The answer has comments that are relevant

Comment: I personally find it on topic. There would eventually be an embed code to copy and paste and worst case scenario people providing alternatives will most likely lead to API examples. All it needs for the question to be on topic is to word it differently. I personally appreciate well formulated questions but I would NOT ask for a question to be worded differently for the sole purpose of being on topic.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You cannot share media on Instagram using the API. [See the docs](https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/):

> At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a
>   conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:
>
> 1. Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos
>      from within the app.
> 2. We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once
>      we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what
>      comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working
>      on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience
>      on our platform.

Comment: The docs link in your answer is not available anymore. Is this still true? I can't find anywhere some clear explanation of this, even in instagram developers page.

Comment: Short answer no, you can use the API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/ or for a mobile app see  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/