# For website How to make Custom Share Button code in html javascript for Instagram same like Pinterest

Tags: javascript, html, instagram, pinterest

for website: How to make Custom Share Button code for Instagram same like Pinterest ?

I am using following custom code / script  for Pinterest and it's working perfectly! , it automatically share your website photos to visitor Pinterest account.

```
<a href='javascript:void((function()%7Bvar%20e=document.createElement(&apos;script&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;type&apos;,&apos;text/javascript&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;charset&apos;,&apos;UTF-8&apos;);e.setAttribute(&apos;src&apos;,&apos;http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinmarklet.js?r=&apos;+Math.random()*99999999);document.body.appendChild(e)%7D)());'>Pin</a>
```

Now anyone please tell me the JavaScript code same type above custom auto share button for Instagram.

Thanks

Comment: Probably here is the answer :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542054/does-instagram-have-share-button-or-not

Answer (score 0):

Instagram doesn't have an API or anyway to post from outside the app at this point. So unfortunately there is no custom JavaScript code to do this right now.